# Update dict value based on length and matche from another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries with values represented as a list that I would like to updates with 0s if there is no match from another list that I am referencing. The 0s should be populate at any index there is no match.

sample data:

```
data = [{'item': ['cat', 'bat'], 'val': [2, 4]},
{'item': ['fat'], 'val': [23]},
{'item': ['cat', 'bat', 'mat'], 'val': [6, 9, 8]}
]

sample = ['aaa', 'aa', 'cat', 'bb', 'fat', 'bbb', 'bat', 'bbbb', 'mat']
```

The data should then look like this:

```
data = [{'item': [0, 0, 'cat', 0, 0, 0, 'bat', 0, 0], 'val': [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0 4, 0, 0]},
{'item': [0, 0, 0, 0, 'fat', 0, 0, 0, 0], 'val': [0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
{'item': [0, 0, 'cat', 0, 0, 0, 'bat', 0, 'mat'], 'val': [0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 8]}
]
```

I tried using for loops to get the length of each value in the list of dictionaries and append the 0s, but this method does not account for the matches that occur before an element in the dict.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming, there are no duplicities in `item` key or in `sample` list:

```py
data = [
    {"item": ["cat", "bat"], "val": [2, 4]},
    {"item": ["fat"], "val": [23]},
    {"item": ["cat", "bat", "mat"], "val": [6, 9, 8]},
]

sample = ["aaa", "aa", "cat", "bb", "fat", "bbb", "bat", "bbbb", "mat"]

tmp = dict(zip(sample, range(len(sample))))

for d in data:
    item, val = d["item"], d["val"]
    d["item"] = [0] * len(sample)
    d["val"] = [0] * len(sample)
    for i, v in zip(item, val):
        if not (idx := tmp.get(i)) is None:
            d["item"][idx], d["val"][idx] = i, v

print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "item": [0, 0, "cat", 0, 0, 0, "bat", 0, 0], 
        "val": [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
    },
    {
        "item": [0, 0, 0, 0, "fat", 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        "val": [0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
    {
        "item": [0, 0, "cat", 0, 0, 0, "bat", 0, "mat"],
        "val": [0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 8],
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Basing on *iterators* for `item/val` entries:

```
for d in data:
    i_it, v_it = iter(d['item']), iter(d['val'])
    d['item'], d['val'] = map(list, zip(*[(next(i_it), next(v_it))
                                          if v in d['item'] else (0, 0) 
                                          for v in sample]))

print(data)
```

---

```
[{'item': [0, 0, 'cat', 0, 0, 0, 'bat', 0, 0],
  'val': [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]},
 {'item': [0, 0, 0, 0, 'fat', 0, 0, 0, 0], 'val': [0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
 {'item': [0, 0, 'cat', 0, 0, 0, 'bat', 0, 'mat'],
  'val': [0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 8]}]
```